# adding Columns based on received Objects to Table, via Spring

Tags: sql, spring

Working in Spring, and using H2 for now.

So, I have these two classes/Entities with their repositories working fine if I keep it simple.

Brand, which simply has a name and a price;

and VendingMachine, which has a model and some other properties;

BUT I need to implement this:

Different VendingMachines sell different Brands, for which they have a stock. The Brands it sells are determined when you instantiate the class.

So my idea is that the table for VendingMachines fields should look something like that:

MODEL////ID/////MAXCAPACITY////MAXBRANDS///BRAND01////BRAND02///BRAND03...

Where all the BRAND columns are the different Brands the machine sells, assigned at its instantiation as said before. The value will be an Integer.

My original idea was to send this data to the @Entity via a HashMap(Brand, Integer) but I don't know how to make it work once it tries to fit it into the JpaRepository, or even if it is possible this way.

Probably missing some magic Annotation I don't know.

Thanks, hope my question was well explained for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract Brand as new table/entity(read about database normalization).
And after just do one-to-many relationship with that entities(VendingMachines and Brand). would look like that:

```
class Brand 
...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="machine_id")
private VendingMachines machines;
```